# getting data from flask to react

Tags: reactjs, flask

I currently have an app that takes files uploaded on the react front end, and then sends them to a flask backend via axios. The flask backend processes these files, and then creates an image. My problem is: I have no idea how to get that image to the react frontend in a displayable fashion. Anybody have ideas?

Thanks!